# chop hex string in c++ and convert each byte in to decimal

Tags: c++, string

I have hex string of fix length 10.
In c++ I want to chop this string in 5 parts and convert each hex number into decimal and again convert that each decimal numbers in to string.

```
e.g. d3abcd23c9
e.g. after chopping 
str1= d3
str2 = ab
str3 = cd
str4 = 23
str5= c9

 convert each string in to unsigned int no:
 no1 = 211
 no2= 171
 no3= 205
 no4= 35
 no5= 201

 again convert each of this number in to str:
 dstr1 = "211"
 dstr2 = "171"
 dstr3 = "205"
 dstr4 = "35"
 dstr5 = "201"
```

Comment: That sounds fun with all the chopping but, **What exactly is your question?????**

Comment: Explain whats wrong or what you want us to do. Don't ask us to make a code for you without you even trying.

Comment: `if (no_code) { return bad_question }`

Comment: [Standard I/O manipulators `hex` and `dec`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) may come in handy to do this.

Answer (score 2):

So your question consists of 5 parts:

1. Chop off a hex string of length 10 to 5 hex strings with 2 characters in each.
2. Convert the resulting array of hex strings into decimal.
3. Store the decimal values in an array of unsigned int.
4. Convert that array of unsigned integers to strings.
5. Save the resulting strings into a string array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string hexstr = "d3abcd23c9"; //your hex
    string str[5]; //To store the chopped off HEX string into 5 pieces
    unsigned int no[5]; //To store the converted string array (HEX to DEC)
    string dstr[5]; //Stores the results of converting unsigned int to string
    int x=0; //

    for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) // Fixed length 10 in chunks of 2 => 10/2 = 5
    {
        str[i] = hexstr.substr(x, 2); //Part 1
        x += 2; //Part 1

        no[i] = std::strtoul(str[i].c_str(), NULL, 16); //Part 2 & 3

        dstr[i] = std::to_string(no[i]); //Part 4 & 5

        cout << dstr[i] << endl; //Just for you to see the result
    }

return 0;
}
```

You can divide the parts into separate for loops consecutively (1 + 2&3 + 4&5) but this approach is cleaner.
Hope this solved it.

Comment: Hi @Hisham Moosa. Welcome to SO. Please add some explanation to your answer to help OP understand where they might have gone wrong - what you have done to solve their problem

Answer (score 0):

*Next time, be careful with your question, because it's not really clear, but I think I understood it. Happy day, I did a code for you, but generally **you must post your code, then someone will help you.***

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

static unsigned int hex2dec(const std::string& val)
{
    unsigned int x;
    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << std::hex << val;
    ss >> x;

    return x;
}

static std::vector<unsigned int> chopperHexStringToDec(const std::string& str, int splitLength = 2)
{
    std::vector<unsigned int> data;
    std::size_t parts = str.length() / splitLength;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < parts; ++i)
        data.push_back(hex2dec(str.substr(i * splitLength, splitLength)));
    if (str.length() % splitLength != 0)
        data.push_back(hex2dec(str.substr(splitLength * parts)));

    return data;
}

int main(int ac, const char **av)
{
    if (ac != 2 || std::strlen(av[1]) != 10)
        return 1;

    std::vector<unsigned int> data = chopperHexStringToDec(av[1]);

    std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator it = data.begin();
    std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator it_end = data.end();
    while (it != it_end)
    {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        ++it;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ss.str("");` this is unnecessary.

Comment: True, I put it before, because I declared my std::stringstream on the loop :D